# From 2 column csv to 2 color NetworkX graph

Tags: ipython, nodes, networkx, graph-databases, edges

I want to create a large networkx graph connecting users to the videos they watch like user -> video in a social graph or network type of graph. There are about 9000 user nodes and 20000 video nodes.

Example CSV File

user, video

1, 11

2, 11

3, 11

4, 12

5, 12

5, 13

What I am trying?

```
G=nx.read_edgelist("test.csv", delimiter = ',', data=['user','highlight'], create_using=nx.Graph())

nx.draw(G)
```

What I get: A graph with all red nodes.

What I want: I want the user nodes to be red and the video nodes to be blue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

file_edges=csv.reader(open('test.csv','rb'));

G=nx.Graph();
users=[];
video=[];
for row in file_edges:
    G.add_node(row[0],type='user');
    users.append(row[0]);
    G.add_node(row[1],type='video');
    video.append(row[1]);
    G.add_edge(row[0],row[1]);

pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes
fig=plt.figure(1)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111);
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos=pos,nodelist=users,with_labels=True,node_size=150,node_color='red',node_shape='s', width=1.75,linewidths=0.2,font_size=5,font_family='serif')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos=pos,nodelist=video,with_labels=True,node_size=150,node_color='blue',node_shape='s', width=1.75,linewidths=0.2,font_size=5,font_family='serif')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist=G.edges(), width=3, edge_color='black');
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,nodelabels=G.nodes(),font_size=8,font_family='serif',font_color='white',font_weight='bold')
ax.legend(['users','video'],loc=2,numpoints=1,scatterpoints=1,prop={'size':10}) # Scatterpoints will show the node marker (say square) only once
plt.gcf()
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't work because row[0] includes the user and highlight columns and row[1]  doesn't exist.

Comment: From your comment, what I understand that data is not getting delimited by ",". So if you split the `row[0].split(",")` and take the first element and the second element in the array it should work. PS: Code written in my answer works. Also check your input file again.